# Generating build in react-native after mapmyindia sdk setup gives build failed error

Tags: javascript, react-native, build.gradle, mapmyindia-api

I am trying to use [mapmyindia](https://developer.mappls.com/) for maps in my react native project but after setting up all steps for sdk and everything, it gives me build failed error and I am not able fix it.

Followed all steps given here: https://github.com/mappls-api/mappls-react-native-sdk/blob/main/docs/v1.0.2/Getting-Started.md

Error it throws while build generation using **npx react-native run-android**:

> BUILD FAILED in 15s error Failed to install the app. Command failed
> with exit code 1: ./gradlew app:installDebug
> -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of
> task ':app:processDebugResources'. Could not resolve all task
> dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > Could
> not find com.mappls.sdk:mappls-android-sdk:8.1.2.

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch error. Have you tried using a version other than 8.1.2?

Comment: Where to check that? I cant see anything related version in their gihub doc.